# SystemVerilog port kind [net or variable]?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need a clarification on SystemVerilog [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), ports section 23.2.2.3.

The LRM says when the port kind (net type or variable) is omitted on `input` port, it defaults to net type, but when the `input` port is of `bit` data type without specifying the port kind, does it infer to net type according to LRM?

A reply would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The port kind defaults to a net and you referenced, but *6.7.1 Net declarations with built-in net types* says that net types are restricted to 4-state integral types. So you should get an error if you try to declare `input bit` instead of `input var bit`.

Note that earlier versions of the SystemVerilog LRM had the default port kind a variable when specifying a data type without a port kind. Some tools might not generate an error if they are not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

"bit" only specifies the data type, not the net type, of a signal.

When you declare a port as "input bit foo", the tools are supposed to infer net type based on whatever `default_nettype is set to.

A number of verilog style guides have recommended "`default_nettype none" as a poor-mans linting tool to detect typos in net names.  This breaks under systemverilog, in so far as it then starts requiring that everything be declared with both a net and a data type, like this:

```
input wire bit foo
```

Everybody hates that, so instead:

- don't use "`default_nettype none"
- use a real linting tool to do linting instead.